# How to get a list of computers or devices on the network and their IP addresses and name, using iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am trying to develop an application where I list out all the peripherals (computers, mobile devices, printers, etc) connected to a local network and their IP addresses. I am new to network programming.  Can any one help me out on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to discover services attached to the network through [Bonjour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonjour_%28software%29), in this case, apple provides [various levels of abstraction](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/GS_Networking_iPhone/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007301) to normal socketing.

Comment: @Sameer Do u find any solution for this